# How can I get the BaskervilleMT font?

Tags: fonts

I would like my documents to use the font in the screenshot below. The font is BaskervilleMT. Does anyone have an idea of how to get it? Or, does anyone know how to get a font that looks like this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: google suggests the font is available from lots of places, it can be bought from here https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/monotype-hk/m-sung-prc/light/ for example, but it is a font for Chinese and you are showing English, are you sure that is the font you want?

Comment: where does the image you posted come from, do you have a pdf of that document?

Comment: Hi David, yes I'm sure that's the font I want - it's used by the journal Philosophical Quarterly. Here's a link to a paper on their website where you can find pdfs of papers: https://academic.oup.com/pq/issue

Comment: I don't think I can get the pdf from there without an account but if you have it the pdffonts utility or the fonts menu item in acrobat and other pdf viewers will tell you which fonts are in the file. It would seem bizarre to use a CJK font for an English language journal but if that is really what it is it can be bought from several places as I note above.

Comment: Without an account I could only get things like the ToC and the backmatter, which usd (different versions of) Baskerville.

Comment: Hi both, I don't have Adobe or anything like that. Here is a link to a paper from that journal which is open access: https://academic.oup.com/pq/article/70/278/114/5556076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pdffonts pqz049.pdf
```

running pdffonts on the pdf linked in a comment shows

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
INOJNF+MTSY                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    101  0
INOJME+BaskervilleMT-Bold            Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     102  0
INOJGF+BskvillExpMT                  Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     66  0
INOJGE+BaskervilleMT                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      67  0
INOJGD+BskvillExpMT-Italic           Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    103  0
INOJGC+BaskervilleMT-Italic          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      68  0
TKYZOR+ArialMT                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no       1  0
INOKCE+MTMI                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    100  0
INOKHD+MTSYB                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    126  0
INOKJD+BskvillExpMT-Bold             Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    137  0
```

that is, it is using (mostly) BaskervilleMT,. The font in the title of this question is not used (which is not surprising as it is not a font for the Latin script)

Comment: Hi David - thanks for this. Sorry about the confusion - whatthefont led me astray! I'm quite new to LaTeX, so how do I get BaskervilleMT?

Comment: there are several baskerville clones around try  `\usepackage{baskervillef}` for example `textdoc baskervillef` for the various options it has.  The MT version is monotype's version you could buy from https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/baskerville-mt/ if you really want that.